# Django admin panel redirects and URL issues: Incorrect paths in admin sites

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django app for a REST API, and I also need to use the Django admin for some tasks. When I run the app locally and try to access the admin panel with the URL `http://localhost:8000/admin`, Django redirects me to `http://localhost/localhost/admin`. Also, when I try to access the login panel as `http://localhost:8000/admin/login`, I can see a valid login page. However, after clicking on 'Log In', a POST request is sent to `http://localhost:8000/lo/admin/login/`.

I checked how HTML files are created for Django admin. I found a variable, `app_path`, that is passed to the template for creating the login page. The value for this variable is assigned in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py` as `app_path': request.get_full_path()`. I created an endpoint to test the values returned from the get_full_path() function. When I call the endpoint `http://localhost:8000/api/getadminurls`, the value from get_full_path() is `http/api/getadminurls`. From all of this, I came to the conclusion that Django is not able to find the correct values that should be filled into those templates, but I was not able to find how to fix this.